# Getting values from local variables in another procedure in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, procedure, local-variables

I am currently learning how to program but I don't understand how to access a local variable from one procedure in order to use that variable's value in a different procedure. I am using Python version 3.5.2 and I have confirmed that the code will work when not divided into procedures.

```
#This program will ask for the users age, weight and birth month, compare
#the input values to secret answers and return a response based on the input.

def main():
    age=0
    weight=0
    month=""

    age=float(input("What is your age? "))
    weight=float(input("What is your weight? "))
    month=input("What is your birth month? ")
    evaluate()

def evaluate():
    if age<=25:
        print("Congratulations, the age is 25 or less!")
    elif weight>=128:
        print("Congratulations, the weight is 128 or more!")
    elif month=='April':
        print("Congratulations, the birth month is April!")

main()
```

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter. So, `def evaluate(age)` and call it with `evaluate(age)`.

Comment: There is no modules, `evaluate()` is function, you need to pass variable to it, such as `age`, `weight`, `month`

Comment: @MorganThrapp thank you for your fast response. You and vishes_shell helped me understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So just to show what the commenters said:

```
def evaluate(theage, theweight, themonth):
    if theage<=25:
        print("Congratulations, the age is 25 or less!")
    elif theweight>=128:
        print("Congratulations, the weight is 128 or more!")
    elif themonth=='April':
        print("Congratulations, the birth month is April!")
#end of evaluate()

def main():
    # ... your existing code ...
    evaluate(age, weight, month)
```

`evaluate()` goes before `main()` so that `main()` knows about `evaluate()`.  Define things first, then reference them, and you will avoid obscure problems (although, as someone will certainly point out, that's not always required).

The parameters to `evaluate` are listed between the `()`.  The values are then passed when `evaluate()` is called from `main()`.  I renamed the parameters to `evaluate()` to show you that the names don't have to be the same.  With the code above, `theage` in `evaluate()` gets a copy of the value of `age` in `main()`.  The same goes for `theweight` and `weight`, and for `themonth` and `month`.

Comment: *"evaluate() goes before main() so that main() knows about evaluate()"* this isn't true. Names inside functions are dynamically looked up when the function is invoked. `main` can reference anything it pleases you just need to make sure it exists (if it was top-level your statement would hold true, of course).

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Yes, hence my parenthetical remark in the answer.  Since the OP is new at Python, I am *personally* recommending define-before-use.  In my personal experience, which is different from yours, define-before-use reduces the chance of astonishment (e.g., due to top-level vs. within-function).

Comment: @cxw Thank you for the advice with define-before-use, I'll be sure to use this when creating new programs as you suggest.

Comment: @JakobWilliams Glad to help, and welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  If this answer helped you, would you please upvote (triangle); if it solved your problem, would you please accept (checkmark)?  Accepting an answer clears the question off the "unanswered" lists and gives us both reputation points :) .